# How to subtract time from date and time

Tags: mysql

I get a `enddatetime` field that is auto generated. I also have a `totaltime` that is being stored in to mysql. I want to subtract `enddatetime` from `totaltime` to get `startdatetime` and `datetimeofevent`.

Example

totaltime= 14:00:00

enddatetime = 5/14/2018 15:00:00

I am currently using date_sub function but its subtracting the hh from yy which is worng.

```
DATE_SUB(enddatetime , INTERVAL (TimeDIFF(totaltime, Time(enddatetime ))) HOUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract time part from enddatetime from the first part of date_sub

Comment: I tried doing that and it did not work. Do you have an example of how it should work

Answer (score 0):

dateTimeDIFF function returns the difference in time format like 12:30:50 
and 
DATE_SUB expects the interval to be integer value
you need to convert from time format to integer 
you can use time_to_sec function to convert the time to number of seconds then devide by 360 to convert seconds to hours or use seconds instead of hours.

example

```
DATE_SUB(enddatetime , INTERVAL (time_to_sec((TimeDIFF(totaltime, Time(enddatetime ))))/3600) HOUR)
```